# Code Review Reports in TFS, Closing Comments vs. Over all Comments

Tags: tfs, tfs-2015, tfs-reports, tfs-code-review

I'm writing a query in TFS that collect all the code reviews conducted in one project, I want to gather comments that have been added. In the field selections I can't find other that "closing comments", while in the code review itself it called overall comments, I'm confused, are those two the same?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They are not the same.

**Closing Comments** is the comment entered by the reviewer when closing the review request. `Reference name=Microsoft.VSTS.CodeReview.ClosingComment`. See [Code review and feedback field reference](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/work/guidance/guidance-code-review-feedback-field-reference#codereviews) for more information.

**Overall Comments** are the comments added by reviewers with the response while changing/fixing the code during the review.

[image]